# React native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null

Tags: react-native

I've encountered some problem in `react-native-permissions` library, although I updated my pods.

Here's my `podfile`

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
```

After adding that, I tried to clean my build folder from xcode and update my pods `pod install` but still encounters the error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:149 Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null.

ExceptionsManager.js:149 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

The weird thing is when I try to run my app in android, it still occurs.

I also tried to remove `node_modules` and reinstall but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix it by removing the `^` in my `package.json` so from  `"react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",` to  `"react-native-permissions": "3.6.1",`

Comment: Saving hours this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Version 3.6.1 works
do not use 3.8.0 - Kills your time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work.

Comment: It could be linking problem. Try npx `react-native link react-native-permissions`

Answer (score 0):

for me the error was causing because of react-native-permissions, and i was using react-native-qrcode-scanner.

I've tried all above method, all was giving me same error. I fixed it downgrading react-native-permissions version to 3.6.1 and its working fine!

the latest version 3.8.0 has some issues.