# Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing this error while starting react native android app.
`Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. To fix this issue try these steps: • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run` pod install`in the`ios `directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods. • If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. You can use this to get started: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/blob/master/mock.js If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions`

I have followed the steps mentioned in the error body no luck.
steps I followed:

1. pod install
2. clean and rebuild the app
3. npx react-native-clean-project

My pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
# pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone.podspec"
pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'BayQi' do
  pod 'react-native-contacts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-contacts'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])



  target 'BayQiTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
end

target 'BayQi-tvOS' do
  # Pods for BayQi-tvOS

  target 'BayQi-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it with following steps

change your react-native-permissions version from 3.8.0 to 2.0.2 in package.json file considering an open issue in the library, reference - https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/411.

add following to the Podfile

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
```

Don't forget to add .podspec at the end, remember this is an older version of react-native-permissions.

add these to Info.plist file

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our app need your permission to use your camera phone</string>
<!-- Include this only if you are planning to use the camera roll -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
```

Make sure you have react-native-camera package added for the camera to be working.

Now run npm install and pod install from ios folder.

Comment: Change your react-native-permissions version from 3.8.0 to 2.0.2 in package.json file - For me it's working for android.

Answer (score 20):

This is because `react-native-qrcode-scanner` uses the old version `react-native-permissions`. One of the typical solutions for such a case is to override dependencies. Override the `react-native-permissions` dependency for `react-native-qrcode-scanner`. For npm we need to use overrides, and for resolutions for yarn.

So for this code works just delete node_modules folder, yarn.lock file, and add this code to package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  },
```

Than run yarn or npm imstall.
My package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
...
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
...
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
...
  },
...
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  },
```

With yarn this package.json works well.

Comment: Ok after I afew attempts I figured out what you were saying. Delete the `react-native-qrcode-scanner\node_modules` folder (not the main node_modules folder which would be insane). Then add the code to the package.json file of your app. This does however then give me `RNPermissionsModule' could not be found`.  And I have also been getting `Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.` this entire time too.

Comment: @Reddspark run yarn or npm install after removing node_modules and adding dependencies. Then rebuild your app, and even if you see the same issue, reload your build. This works for me, I hope it works for you.

Comment: this answer fixed my issue, i was having the same problem with react-native-qrcode-scanner

Answer (score 10):

After spending two days debugging `react-native-permissions`, I found my issue was with `react-native-qrcode-scanner`.

It had `"react-native-permissions": "^2.0.2"` in it's dependencies but the current version is `"react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"`.

This version of `react-native-permissions (3.8.0)` has breaking changes.

**Quick fix**

1. Install `react-native-permissions` and follow the installation instructions.
2. Delete `node_modules/react-native-qrcode-scanner/node_modules/react-native-permissions` because it installs the deprecated `2.0.2`. (You'll need to do this each time you clear your node_modules)

In your case, you'll need to find the library which installs `react-native-permissions` as a dependency and then delete `node_modules/*specific-library*/node_modules/react-native-permissions`

https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/403

Comment: I got 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. after I performed these steps then tried running the app. Also the link you posted talks about it working on Android but not IOS. In my case it doesn't work on either.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue, and solved with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75789461/12357985

Short:
Use react-native-permissions package "3.6.0" version without "^" character in your package.json file.

```json
...
"react-native-permissions": "3.6.1",
...
```

After changing your package.json file, remove package-lock.json and node_modules. Then install packages and run app.

Problem reason:

> Problem occurs between "react-native-qrcode-scanner" and
> "react-native-permissions" packages. Default, package installer
> installs new version(currently: 3.8.0) of "react-native-permissions",
> but you need old and compatible version(currently: 3.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

***This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialisation error when loading React Native***

### If your error also contains this statement you can check for dependency mismatches in your node-modules.

In my case, the react-native-qr dependencies versions are mismatched so I just removed the **react-native-permissions** file in node-modules>react-native-qr-nodemodules>react-native-permissions.